# Повторения в словарях, сложение значений повторяющихся ключей

Tags: python, словари, dict

Вводится число - кол-во вводимых пар(ключ + значение), затем сами пары.
Пример:
3
A: 35
B: 58
A: 54
Как сложить значения повторяющихся ключей? В данном случае 35 + 54
P.s. ключ и значения разделяются ": ". Я убираю это с помощью списка(.split)
Пробовал через .keys но у меня не получилось, хотя, возможно, что-то неправильно писал в вычислениях

Comment: приводите свой код в вопросах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторений ключей в словаре быть не может. Поэтому сложение значений производится на этапе ввода:

```py
n = int(input("Введите количество пар: "))
res = {}
for _ in range(n):
    key, value = input().split(": ") 
    if key in res:
        res[key] += int(value)
    else:
        res[key] = int(value)

print(res)

'''
Введите количество пар: 3
A: 35
B: 58
A: 54
{'A': 89, 'B': 58}
'''
```